# AngularJS change views between collection items

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, I'm facing a logic problem here, well I'm iterating from a object to create a list of `<options>` in my `<select>`

Well, now I need to switch the views for the correspondent selected option

```
<div>
    <select class="select"
        name="singleSelect"
        ng-model="$ctrl.currentViewOption">
        <option value="">Choose a option</option>
        <option ng-selected="$ctrl.selected(item)"
            value="{{item.token}}"
            ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.listOptions">{{'Option '}} {{ $index + 1 }}</option>
    </select>
    <code>selection={{$ctrl.currentViewOption}}</code>
    <hr/>
    <div class="animate-switch-container"
        ng-switch on="$ctrl.currentViewOption">
        <div class="animate-switch" ng-switch-when="item.token === correspondentView">view1</div>
        <div class="animate-switch" ng-switch-when="">view2</div>
        <div class="animate-switch" ng-switch-default>default</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The structure of each option is:

{
    "token": "56e6fe65712ed797f7014d40",
    "status": 3,
    "createdAt": "someDate",
    "updatedAt": "someDate",
    "content": ["this will contain all data to render an option view"]
  }

So, what can I do on my controller, to switch views based on each on this items?
for each view I will render data based on `content` attr of this object

Answer (score 1):

The value you set for the ng-switch-when directive is a string, not an expression. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch

If you want to be able to switch based on some property, content for example, of the currentViewOption, you would have to use something like:

```
 <div class="animate-switch-container"
    ng-switch on="$ctrl.currentViewOption.content">
    <div class="animate-switch" ng-switch-when="stringValueNecessaryToShowView1">view1</div>
    <div class="animate-switch" ng-switch-when="stringValueNecessaryToShowView2">view2</div>
    <div class="animate-switch" ng-switch-default>default</div>
</div>
```

In this example when the currentViewOption.content == 'stringValueNecessaryToShowView1', then view1 will be shown.